# Truecrypt rescue usb

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, grub, truecrypt

i have found tutorials on their official forum and on the internet about how to make a truecrypt rescue bootable usb stick.

I'm guessing anyone who can answer will know what that is already, but it is basically just a way to boot into the system using a usb stick instead of a DVD.

But the only problem is all of these tutorials involve using Grub4Dos, and i cannot run Grub4Dos on 64 bit windows 7.

Is there any other alternative method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syslinux](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php) boot loader is able to [boot ISO images](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK#ISO_images).

Comment: i have windows system

Comment: I know. "Syslinux" can be installed from Windows too.